# $\mathrm{Out}(F_{2})=\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$, but $F_{2}=\Gamma(2)$

Tags: gr.group-theory

I am trying to align the following facts.

- The free group with two generators $F_{2}$ is isomorphic to a congruence subgroup $\Gamma(2)\le\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$.
- The outer automorphism group of $F_{2}$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Surely the action of $\mathrm{Out}(F_{2})=\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ on $F_{2}=\Gamma(2)$ is not via conjugation. What is this action? Is there a neat, direct description of this action?

Added: It might be a long shot but what ultimately I wanted to ask was if there is a nice description of this action without really referring to $F_{2}$.

Comment: The action of outer automorphisms is never by conjugation (by definition, otherwise it would be inner!). You can find a detailed account of automorphisms of free groups in Lyndon-Schupp, Chapter I, §4, including $\operatorname{Out}(F_2)$. For example Proposition 4.5 gives explicit generators for $\operatorname{Out}(F_2)$ and the generators of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ they are mapped (isomorphically) to.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: Of course your point is overall correct, but may be worth noting that we can have $H\subseteq G$ and conjugation by certain elements of $G$ (not in $H$) give outer automorphisms of $H$. This happens with some of the simple Lie groups, I believe.

Comment: @SamHopkins Ah, that's a good point. I guess the question is asking for slightly more than just a description of $\operatorname{Out}(F_2)$.

Comment: The group $Out(F_n)$ acts on the abelianization $F_n^{\text{ab}} = \mathbb{Z}^n$ of $F_n$.  This gives a homomorphism $Out(F_n) \rightarrow Out(\mathbb{Z}^n) = Aut(\mathbb{Z}^n) = GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$.  For $n=2$, this is an isomorphism, but for higher $n$ it is surjective but not injective (its kernel is called the "Torelli subgroup" of $Out(F_n)$).

Comment: (in other words, your first point is just a red herring and has nothing to do with the action you're looking for [which is not an action at all anyway, but an *outer action*, so you should be suspicious if you see something that looks like an actual action])

Comment: $\Gamma(2)$ is actually not free. For example it contains $-I$ (this is a common mistake). However there is a subgroup of $\Gamma(2)$ which is free, which is sometimes called the [Sanov subgroup](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sanov_subgroup_in_SL(2,Z)).

Comment: @SamHopkins This happens with all simple groups, because $H$ is naturally a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ whenever $Z(H) = 1$.

Comment: You can take the universal family of punctured elliptic curves over the moduli space of elliptic curves, $\mathcal M_{1,2} \to \mathcal M_{1,1}$. An issue is that the isomorphism $F_2 \cong P\Gamma(2)$ represents it as the fundamental group of $\mathbb P^1$ punctured at $3$ points, not an elliptic curve punctured at one point, and the $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$-action isn't visible there.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Indeed, for any group $G$, every automorphism can be realised as conjugation by an element of an overgroup, simply via the Cayley embedding of $G$ in $Sym(G)$.

Comment: What is usually denoted by $\Gamma(2)$ (at least, in areas I am familiar with) is a subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ rather then $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. (And yes, it is isomorphic to $F_2$.)